# AddRequest Is Not Respected in HttpURLConnection

Tags: android

I am trying to attach the ["Accept-Language" header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) to a get request that I am making but when I check the request using [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) then the header is not there. I add the header like so.

```
private HttpURLConnection getConnection(Uri uri) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty(ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_HEADER, LanguageProvider.getLanguage());
    return urlConnection;
}
```

The odd this is if I log the requestproperties after I add then I can see it is set in the HttpURLConnection. Why is this removed before it is sent?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the following headers where added automatically

> Host  appname-api-staging.herokuapp.com
>
> User-Agent Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JLS36I)
>
> Proxy-Connection  Keep-Alive

I modified my code to try and change the User-Agent so like

```
    URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "test");
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty(ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_HEADER, LanguageProvider.getLanguage());
```

Lo and behold this changes the host header to "test". What is the difference between adding a new request property and modifying and old one?

Answer (score 0):

something like this works for me: `httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");`

hence, you should do `httppost.setHeader(ACCEPT_LANGUAGE_HEADER, "es_ES")` if u want to read Don Quijote in the original language... :P

BTW, I use the HttpClient:

```
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, HTTP_CON_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, HTTP_CON_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(baseUrl);
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
```

Comment: I am using httpurlconnection not httppost. This is the recommended class in later version of android

Comment: mmh... Use the HttpClient, that way u´ve got control on http result codes, headers, cookies, aaaaaall the common stuff

Comment: the android team suggest using httpurlconnection which has the same and more features http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html

I would prefer to fix the issue rather than implement a very big work around

Comment: yup... could be... google discouraged maven and gradle and now they´re building android studio basing it on those... I suppose it was kind of astrategy to take over the free market. For now ALMOST ALL Apache F. projects use that class and, if not in the SDK, I´d probably add it myself to my applications

Comment: Interesting perspective, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, and the original poster has probably moved on, but this answer is for anyone else (like me) who seems to have the same issue.

The problem may not be in the `HttpURLConnection` at all. It may be related to the name of the header and the server's configuration. I ran similar tests, such as pausing execution and checking to see if the header I added was set in the `HttpURLConnection` (and it was), changing the value of another header that was added automatically (which did work), and changing the name of the header to some test name such as XYZ, which worked; I was able to retrieve the value on the server side. And one more, I used an HTTP tool to set the header and send the request. That also only worked if I changed the name of the header.

So, in my case, the problem was on the server side. Apache or PHP was removing the header for some reason. So as a workaround/solution, I added the following directives to apache configuration:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Header_Name} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_HEADER_NAME:%1]
```